# osx cannot find an executable in the current directory

Tags: macos, chmod

I got stuck when chmod a file.

At the bottom of [this page](http://bsc2010.bioinformatics.ucdavis.edu/handson/linux_bootcamp_workshop.html),about "**Scripts**", I did san exercise according to the guide. But en error appeared. Mac OS X, the information on the command line listed below.

```
$ nano myscript
$ chmod 755 myscript
$ myscript
-bash: myscript: command not found
```

I am confused. Could you point out the question? Any responses would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is not in your path.  Use `./myscript`.

Comment: Hi Adam and Dave, I tried to use ./myscript on the command line  according to your suggestions, it works now. Thank you two very much!
P.S. I am a novice.

Answer (score 2):

If you type `echo $PATH` you'll see a list of the directories that will be checked, in order, for executables.  Your current path is probably *not* in that list, for security reasons<sup>*</sup>.  To execute a file in the current directory, which is written `.`, use `./myscript`.

---

<sup>*</sup> Although it may seem inconvenient, there's a very good reason for requiring you to specify the current directory explicitly if you want to execute a file there.  Suppose that were *not* the case, and you could simply type the file's name to execute the version in the current directory.  Now imagine someone were to create a script in that directory called `ls`, whose contents were `rm *`.  Worse, a malicious script called `ssh` might capture your login credentials.

You can alter this behavior by changing the `PATH` variable to include the current directory like this:  `export PATH=$PATH:.` (to search the current directory last), or `export PATH=.:$PATH` (to search the current directory first).  But you need to be aware of the security risks, and then decide that this is a good idea anyway.

This is why, by default, linux systems should *never* include `.` in the `PATH` for the root user—the only thing worse than executing a malicious file is executing a malicious file when you have root privileges.

Comment: Hi Adam, it's really important about security. I got it. Thank you very much!